# Oracle SQL / PLSQL : I need to copy data from one database to another

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have two instances of the same database, but data is only committed to the "original" one. I need to copy inserted data from certain tables and commit them to the same tables in the second DB automatically. How can I do it?

I've already created synonyms for the tables in the second DB on original and within a specially prepared trigger I tried to use `INSERT INTO ...` statement with `:new.` but it is causing the data to not be committed anywhere and I receive Oracle Errors like:

> ORA-02291: integrity constraint (PRDBSHADOW.FK_ED_PHY_ENT) violated.

Here is my trigger code

```
create or replace TRIGGER INS_COPY_DATA
AFTER INSERT ON ORIGDB.TABLE_A
REFERENCING NEW AS NEW OLD AS OLD

FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN

  insert into COPY_TABLE_A(val1,val2,val3,val4) values (:new.val1, :new.val2, :new.val3, :new.val4);

END;
```

Comment: you need to do it only once or you want to copy each time when data is inserted in the original one.

Comment: I need it every time data is inserted to original table.

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add the complete code of your stored procedure

Comment: Its's hard to tell, because the error doesn't relate to the example table names. But it's an FK error, so the most likely reason seems to be that COPY_TABLE_A has a reference to COPY_TABLE_B, but you didn't copy the data from TABLE_B to COPY_TABLE_B, or you did, but with a different primary key. TL;DR: What @a_horse_with_no_name said. :-)

Comment: The error message seems clear to me. A database constraint is being violated. From the constraint name, I'm guessing it's a _foreign key_ constraint. Can you [edit] your question and add the definition for the constraint named `FK_ED_PHY_ENT` in schema `PRDBSHADOW`?

Comment: CONSTRAINT "FK_ED_ORD_ENT" FOREIGN KEY ("MEID", "MECREATOR", "MESID")
   REFERENCES "PRDBSHADOW"."MES" ("MEID", "MECREATOR", "MESID") ENABLE

Comment: So it would mean that I need to also prepare data for that table?

Comment: In your question, the constraint name is `FK_ED_PHY_ENT` but in your comment it is `FK_ED_ORD_ENT`. Which is correct?

Comment: Ach, sorry. I have three tables with similar name, small mistake but I can say that this FK is basically the same for each of them, so you could treat it like that.

Comment: _So it would mean that I need to also prepare data for that table?_ If you understand what a **foreign key** constraint is and how it works, it would see that the answer to your question is _yes_, you first need to make sure the referenced table contains the relevant values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the entry in parent table is missing here. At least the FK ending of constraint is telling me so.

It means you need to insert first all the data into a "parent" table in order to be able to insert records in a "child".

For example the table auto_maker is having 3 rows only: Audi, Peugeot, and Honda.
Another table named "model" has 2 columns "maker" and "model". "maker" is a foreign key referencing to the "auto_maker" table.

It means in the models table are only the records allowed whose "maker" column value  exists in "auto_maker" table.

In other words only these are available:

maker      model
Audi       A4
Peugeot    308
Honda      Accord

Of course you can enter every model you wish, but "maker" value has to exist in the auto_maker table.

This is what probably happen - the trigger tries to insert a data in a column which is referencing to a "parent" table and the :new value just doesn't exist.

The following script will let you know what table you need to fill first.

```
select aic.index_owner, aic.table_name, aic.column_name
  from all_constraints uc,
       all_ind_columns aic
 where aic.INDEX_NAME = uc.r_constraint_name
   and uc.table_name = 'TABLE_A'
   and uc.constraint_type = 'R';
```

If the query returns something just create similar triggers on those tables with similar logic you already have